# Appending 2 Elements in protractor to form a Expected Element

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, protractor, cucumber

I have a following elements in PageObjectModel in Pages as

this.Element1 = element.all(by.css('card div[class*="card-container"] div'));

this.Element2 = element(by.css('div'))

Is there anyway i can add this 2 ElementFinder's in a method like
'''
await **Element1**.then(async function(row){

For(let i=0; i< row.length;i++)

{

```
await row[i].**`Element2`**.getText().then(async function(Text){

});
```

}

});
'''

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Do you want an array of the text for two separate elements?

Comment: Combination of those 2 elements will form a single element and i should be able to select or click on that element.

Comment: Are you talking about child elements? Finding an element based on another (usually higher level) element

Comment: I have updated the Question now.Can you please help

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear what outcome you are hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

protractor gave an example here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.element

You can create child elements a.k.a sub elements.

Example:

```
let item = element(by.id('test'));
let child = item.element(by.css('something'));
let child2 = child.element(by.tag('div'));
let text = await child2.getText();
```

Comment: Element1.then(async function(row){.  For(let i=0; i<row.length;i++).                              row[i].Element2.getText()                });

Comment: Thanks for tour reply. In the above example can i add as below let                           
let item = element(by.id('test'));
let child = element(by.css('something'));
let child2 = item.child.getText().then(async function(Text){

});

Comment: the await will wait for async response and text will be the string. then() nesting is bad practice. use async await

Comment: @DtestA additional to that, element is an object not promise so you can nest them. every operation to this element become an async operation and have to be awaited example getText(), sendText()